# How to multiply two datasets by groups for two months separately in its own column using R

Tags: r

I have a dataset, it contains a group(`idgroup`) and its coefficient (`coef` column).
Small example

```
groups=structure(list(idgroup = c(1L, 3L, 4L), coef = c(2.1, 1.7, 1.3
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

and a dataset with percentages.
Small example

```
perc = structure(list(idgroup = c(1L, 2L, 4L, 5L), percent = c(0.4753, 
0.5392, 0.48, 0.51), month_id = c(202304L, 202304L, 202305L, 
202305L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

how to multiply the values of the coefficients that are in the `groups` table for those  percent value of `idgroups` that are in the `perc` table?
in this case is it only `idgroups`=1 and 4.

I can do it myself, but the difficulty is that it must be done separately for each `month_id`
in this case, we have only 2 of them. (for example, 202304,202305)
But only in such a way that each month was in its own column

In other words, the desired output should look like this

```
  idgroup month_id1 month_id2
1       1   0.99813        NA
2       4        NA     0.624
```

month_id1 is the first month (i.e. 202304) , month_id2 is the second month (i.e. 202305)
in `perс` does not happen for more than 2 months

How can I get such a desired output.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are open to a `tidyverse` based solution, this might give you what you are looking for:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

groups %>% 
  inner_join(perc, by = "idgroup") %>% 
  mutate(value = coef * percent, .keep = "unused") %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = month_id, values_from = value)
```

This returns

```r
# A tibble: 2 × 3
  idgroup `202304` `202305`
    <int>    <dbl>    <dbl>
1       1    0.998   NA    
2       4   NA        0.624
```

First we use an `inner_join` to restrict the result to `idgroups` present in both datasets.
Next we calculate the values by multipling `coef` and `percent`, removing `coef` and `percent` at the same time. And finally we bring it into a *wider* form using `pivot_wider`. Here the new column names are based on the `month_id`s.

Or perhaps a `base R` version:

```r
result <- merge(groups, perc, by = "idgroup")
result["value"] <- result$coef * result$percent
result["coef"] <- NULL
result["percent"] <- NULL

reshape(result, idvar = "idgroup", timevar = "month_id", direction = "wide")
```

returning

```r
  idgroup value.202304 value.202305
1       1      0.99813           NA
2       4           NA        0.624
```